# Facebook Graph API Search "Unofficial Results"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Graph API to search for a business's Page. I've included **type=page** in the search query, however the results contain several **Place** results that are listed as **"Unofficial Pages"**.

Is there an easy way to filter the **Unofficial Pages** out of the results? I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this.

For example, a local search is returning the following results for the same business....

Official Page: https://www.facebook.com/Turtle-Creek-Vineyard-1652393331683838/

Unofficial Place: https://www.facebook.com/pages/Turtle-Creek-Vineyard/130640440336061

I would like to figure out how to have the first, official result returned only. Or, if there is parameter that I can use to filter out the unofficial, place results.

Comment: There is no way to do that

Comment: Your classification of those two pages as “official” and “unofficial” is rather arbitrary. This is a case where the owner of that business should request that the two pages be merged (or delete the “unofficial” one, if they created it themselves.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no filter option according to the docs about the Search API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

You will have to filter on your own after getting the results.

Comment: Any idea on what field(s) could be used to filter for this? I tried most of the fields returned, but none of them seem to indicate if the page is "Unofficial". 

The fields are defined here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/#Reading

Comment: oh, i thought you do have a field for that already. well, if there´s nothing in the docs, there´s most likely nothing you can do.

Comment: you could try to request a field that is only available for places: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/place/

Comment: i tried, but it doesn't change the results. it almost seems like there is a bug with the API because setting type=page is bringing back both pages and places.

Comment: temporary hack: using the result with the most **likes** seems to be bringing back the best result for most cases, but not all

Answer (score 0):

Use the Field "is_unclaimed". If it is true, that's mean that the page is "Unofficial Page".